# RxJava subscribe and observe on same thread as unit test

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I want to write a kind of "blackbox test" for a component, that internally uses RxJava.

Internally it uses `Retrofit` which returns an `Observable` to make a httpcall and afterwards it uses `.flatmap()`  to future processing on the data retrieved from retrofit. The idea is to give that component a `Transformer` for setting the schedulers on the observer like this:

```
class DefaultTransformer <T> implements Transformer<T, T> {

   public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) { 
      return observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
   }
}
```

My Component does something like this:

```
void execute(Transformer<T, T> scheduler){
     Observable<List<Team>> observable = retrofitApi.getLeague(leagueId, seasonId)
        .flatMap(new Func1<LeagueWrapper, Observable<List<Team>>>() {
          @Override public Observable<List<Team>> call(LeagueWrapper wrapper) {                
             return Observable.just(wrapper.getLeague().getTeams());
          }
        });

   observable.compose(transformer);

   observable.subscribe(this);
}
```

In production I pass `DefaultTransformer` as parameter, but for Unit tests I want to submit a `Transformer` that runs on the same thread as the unit test, so everything should run in sync (not async).

I tried that:

```
class UnitTestTransformer <T> implements Transformer<T, T> {

       public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) { 
          return observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.test()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.test());
       }
    }
```

But it still runs async in my unit tests.  I also tried `Scheduler.immediate()`. `toBlocking()` seems not to be an option, because it's not an `Observable` anymore. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `observable.compose(transformer);` is the problem. All `Observable` instances are immutable and calling `compose` doesn't change the existing `Observable` but returns a new one (which is ignored in your code). `observable.compose(transformer).subscribe(this)` should work fine.

Comment: One more thing. All `Observable`'s returned by `retrofit` already have a `Scheduler` specified because `retrofit` calls `subscribeOn` internally. Calling `subscribeOn` one more time won't actually change the final scheduler in which the network call will be performed.

Comment: If you want to test your code, you should use `toBlocking` operator (which is used really a lot in most `RxJava` unit tests)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the `compose()` hint! So there is no chance to update the `Scheduler` of retrofit? `toBlock()` will not work for me, because I can't change the `execute()` method of my Component or do you see a workaround for that? The execute method will be internally called (among other non RxJava calls). The only thing i can do is set the `Scheduler` with `Component.setScheduler(Transformer t)` which will be passed as argument to `Component.execute()`

Answer (score 3):

If changing the pattern of how `execute()` is called is not an option, you may want to try using the RxJava Plugin mechanism.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Plugins

You can provide:

- `RxJavaSchedulersHook` to override the schedulers that are provided during test execution and get them to execute synchronously
- `RxJavaObservableExecutionHook` to hook into the Observable execution pipeline and use some kind of synchronization method (like a [CountdownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)) to wait for the Observable subscriptions to finish before continuing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using the class TestObserver (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestObserver.html)

It has the following three methods giving access to the received events:

```
getOnCompletedEvents()
getOnErrorEvents()
getOnNextEvents()
```

I hope this can help you, too, if you can inject your subscriber somehow.
Here is an example how I tested it:

```
TestObserver<MyModel> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
myObservableSupplyingMethod().subscribe(testObserver);

assertThat(testObserver.getOnErrorEvents().size()).isEqualTo(0);
assertThat(testObserver.getOnNextEvents().get(0)).isNotNull();
...
```